# Selenium - count number of elements with matching class

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following test code:

```
    it('count elements by class', async t => {
      let count = await driver.findElements(By.css('my-questions-class')).then(v => v.length);
      assert.equal(count, 3);   // count is 0, but I expect 3
    });
```

in my HTML, it's clear that there are some matching elements:

```
<div class="panel panel-default my-questions-class">
```

is there a good reason why the Selenium code should not pick up these HTML elements?

I also tried this selector instead:

```
By.css('div[class=\'my-questions-class\']')
```

neither one picked up any elements from the page. But I can tell from observation that it is loading the correct page, so not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `By.className` the way you have it written. i.e.

```
By.className('my-questions-class')
```

When using `By.css`, you should use the CSS selector.

```
By.css('.my-questions-class')
```

Or

```
By.css('div.my-questions-class')
```